# Do I need more travel history to get a Norwegian visa

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I have three visas in my passport: Dubai, Turkey and Italy. Do I need more travel history to apply for a Norway visit visa or is that enough?

Answer (score 6):

Norway is part of the Schengen area (most of the European Union, plus Norway, Switzerland and Liechtenstein), which has a common visa scheme. In particular, Schengen includes Italy so if you actually have a multiple-entry Schengen visa that's still valid, you can already travel to Norway. Alternatively, the fact that you've already had a Schengen visa means that you should be able to get another one, unless your circumstances have changed.

Having a travel history is not a requirement for getting a Schengen visa. You will need to demonstrate that you can financially afford your trip and that you are likely to leave the Schengen area at the end of your trip, e.g., because of your job, family and property in your home country. Having travelled to other countries before suggests that you're more likely to return home, but it's probably not a big factor.

Whether or not your application is successful is entirely down to your personal circumstances as you describe them on the form, supported by the evidence you provide. We can't comment on specific cases because we'd only be able to speculate.